# How do I use tf serving with transforming methods?

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-serving

I have a problem. I have a free text, for example: "Today the weather is good" and this free text I would like to predict which class it is. For this I would like to use `tf serving`. I don't put free text directly into the model, but I first clean the sentence and then connect it to a vector.
However, how can I incorporate these steps within the `tf serving` process. My `x_ready` that goes into `model.predict(x_ready)` looks like this:

```py
[[
  0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 
  1 5 987 54
]]
```

How can I call my methods and then pass `tf serving` my `x`?
In addition, I would like to get the probability. How can I get the class and probability with `tf serving`?

That is how I predict a single class

```py
def predict_single(x):    
    # lower the text
    x = x.lower()
    x = remove_URL(x)
    x = remove_punct(x)
    x = remove_stopwords(x)
    
    x = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([x])
    # pad
    x_ready = pad_sequences(x, maxlen=maxlen)
    print(x)
    pred = model.predict(x_ready)
    print("Probability", pred.max(axis=1))
    pred = pred.argmax(axis=1)
    pred = le.classes_[pred]
    
    return pred[0]
    
    # Clean the text
    return x
```

```py
[OUT]
Probability [0.7528353]
Class 3
```

---

How I installed `tf-serving`

```bash
docker pull tensorflow/serving

docker run -it -v C:\Code\tensorflow\demo:/demo-p 8601:8601 --entrypoint /bin/bash tensorflow/serving

tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8601 --model_name=model --model_base_path=/demo/models/
```

How I saved the model

```
model.fit(...)
model.save("models/1")
model.save("models/2")
```

Answer (score 1):

`TF Serving` is mainly used to deploy a trained model to production environment with high performance. `TF Serving` doesn't support with data cleaning and data preprocessing. So if you want to preprocess your inputs and then do inference, you can take a look at the `Tensorflow Transform` component in `TFX` . You can refer the documentation of `TF Transorm` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/get_started).

For getting the probability values, Can you take a look at **Serving saved model with Tensorflow Serving** section of [this blog](https://neptune.ai/blog/how-to-serve-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker), which explains on the same.

Let us know if you have any questions. Thank you!